al enviar un formulario, que aparezca un texto de procesando mientras se envia
Tengo un formulario, que lo único que tiene contiene son input de date, que lo que hacen es agregar las fechas seleccionadas a una consulta de SQL que exporta en un Excel.
El punto es, que mientras se este ejecutando (a veces dura unos 20 segundos) aparezca un texto como "procesando datos" o algo similar y bloquee el boton de enviar.
Pero no se de JS y me esta volviendo un poco loco, porque no encuentro información en internet con respecto a esto o similar.
      <form action="reporte/DiaPuntual/reporte_NACIONAL_dia.php" method="POST" class="form inline my-2 my-lg-0 sclass">
         <label class="rep_text">Fecha </label>
         <input type="date" id="fecha14" name="fecha_diaP" placeholder="Fecha inicio" required class="form-control mr-sm-2" min="2024-03-11"> 
         <br/>
         <input onclick="enviar()" id="btn_modal_g" type="submit" name ="info_TM" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" value="Generar Reporte">
       </form>

Lo unico que pude encontrar, es esto:
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#carga").hide();
  });

   function enviar(){
     $("#carga").show();
     $.ajax({
     url:   'ubicacion url', 
     type:  'POST', 
     success:  function () { 
       $("#carga").hide();
      }
    });
  }

es código lo saque de una consulta de aca, pero la verdad no se como aplicarlo si es que me puede llegar a servir para lo que me gustaría. Si alguien podría guiarme y decirme como podria buscar para investigar, se lo agradecere!

ok pero cual es el problema???

cuando apreto el boton para enviar los input, aparece el texto que puse con el ID "carga" pero no desaparece luego de terminar de enviar el formulario.

y cual parte del codigo es la que se termino de enviar el formulario???

lo que hace el formulario, es enviar los datos del input a otro archivo php, y ese php exporta y descarga un Excel. Prácticamente me doy cuenta que termino cuando veo el archivo descargado. Por eso no se como asociar todo. O a lo mejor deberia poner que cuando termine de descargar ponga algun texto que diga "exito al descargar" en el php del excel. No se como deberia hacerlo

parece que te estas dando cuenta ... que ye hacen falta cosas que desarrollar o controlar ...
